# Performance of iSCSI devices

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, iscsi, san

I am toying around with the idea to use my 2009 Mac Mini as a server. For performance and reliability reasons, I guess I would want to replace its HDD with a SSD. In order to have some disk space available on it, I think about getting a SAN device since this Minis fastest I/O port is Ethernet. **Update**: The first devices that came to my mind were NAS boxes implementing iSCSI.

So my question is: How good is the performance of **these** iSCSI SAN devices? Their performance regarding "file system protocols" seems to scale with the processing power, i.e. an ARM processor with a frequency of more then 2 GHz or Atoms/Power PCs with two cores guarantee satisfying transfer speeds. With iSCSI, is an ARM with 1 GHz sufficient for good transfer speeds?

Comment: Compared to SATA a SCSI device is going to have horrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

> **I think about getting a SAN device since this Minis fastest I/O port is Ethernet.**

An [early Mac Mini](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3153) has the following ports

```
 FireWire (IEEE 1394)            400 Mbit/s max
 10/100/1000 Ethernet           1000 Mbit/s max
 USB 2.0                         480 Mbit/s max
```

I'm not sure the difference in speed should be the primary purchasing criterion.

Perhaps, for the cost of a SAN device, you can buy a NAS device that provides better IO.

> **How good is the performance of iSCSI SAN devices?**

[image]

http://www.rainiersolutions.com/RainierLibrary/iSCSI%20SAN%20Performance.pdf

Comment: I saw these graphs while googleing for an answer. Maybe my question was not sufficiently precise, I will elaborate on it. *P.S.* My Mini has an FW800 port.